# Karate try use some elements inside iframe - iframe - element and doesn't see element ( UI )

Tags: javascript, karate

Karate dsl v0.9.6
My code looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtaSs.png)

And when I try to click my Element - it's doesn't work for me.

I have the next structure of the site:
<iframe1
.....
.....
<iframe2
.....
myElement to be clickable
.....
</iframe2
</iframe1

So, when I try to do something inside iframe1/iframe2 it's doesn't work.
I have these 2 frames on a different domain.

Does it work in Karate? Switching from iframe to iframe2 inside? Or for Karate it wouldn't work?

Comment: karate can switch frames but such questions are impossible to answer without seeing the whole flow / html. so follow this process if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test

Comment: @PeterThomas https://prnt.sc/wnh4qp
 here is the result of * def temp = driver.send({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' })
* print 'temp:', temp
It would be enough for details?

Comment: unfortunately no. so as mentioned in the other issue, see if you can help troubleshoot. note that we are focusing on the 1.0 release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Do you mean, that it's will not work? or it's still not enough details?

Comment: yes, not enough details (for me personally) but maybe someone else here would have a better idea

Comment: @PeterThomas https://prnt.sc/wnhotr from Terminal

Comment: @PeterThomas can we do some chat? Here I cannot use chat right now... but I'm very interested in Karate for UI testing. But the main problem for me is iframe switching.. what is sad..